# Tool for converting tables into 2nd, 3rd and 4th normal forms?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, mysql, database

I'm looking for a tool that will convert a table, in CSV format, into 2nd and 3rd normal forms.

I've found many tutorials and examples on the process, but no tools.

I'm running Windows 7 on PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't think that is possible as you would need to tell the software about the data, which would ultimately be the same as normalising manually.

A similar question was answered [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24748/is-there-a-tool-to-check-if-my-database-is-normalized-to-the-third-normal-form).

In short, it explained that this would be out of the scope of automation but design tools may help you.